# MS Access 2007 : combine cells and transpose data?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a table with look like that:

#### People..........Client

People1............clientA
People1............clientB
People1............clientC
People1............clientD
People2............clientE
People2............clientF
People2............clientG

and the result i want is this one :

#### People............Client

People1.................clientA+clientB+clientC+clientD (it's a single column)
People2.................clientE+clientF+clientG (it's a single column)

The table itself is coming from different request and i have about 20 people with max 30 clients each.
This the sql request type that i'm using to create this table :

SELECT DATA.People, DATA.client
FROM DATA
GROUP BY DATA.People, DATA.client;

I think i need a loop but have no idea of how i should do it.